# C# flaw with Double.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, hash, double

The bit format for doubles stores the sign in the first bit. The C# hash algorithm for double is the binary-xor of the upper and lower 32 bits.

As such, when you hash a double A and its negative, -A, the only difference in the hashes is in the first bit.

To hash multiple fields, most references suggest using something like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

Finally, consider two objects with two doubles each, like so:

Object1: {A, -B}
Object2: {-A, B}

For any two doubles A and B, these two objects seem to always hash to the same value (using the method above, regardless of seed and multiplier). The rationale is, roughly, that the entropy is stored in the most significant bit, and that bit overflows losing important information.

I'm looking to use a different hash for doubles with similar performance but superior entropy.  Any suggestions?

Edit: Please do not write/comment about the inevitability of collisions.

Comment: Do you expect to have a lot of values that only differ with the sign?  Because no matter what you do you'll end up with different values that give the same hash.

Comment: Are you frequently comparing sets of doubles where you have sets that are equal other than the fact that one is the inverse of the other?  Collisions can never be avoided entirely, you can only ever try to avoid patterns *that are actually in the data you're hashing*.

Comment: @juharr It's not even just values that differ in sign, it's specifically pairs that are exactly the inverse sign of other pairs.  When considering a pair that has only one value with a different sign, collisions don't appear to be common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just pointed out why a simple XOR is not a best practice for combining hashes.

For reference, here's how `System.Tuple<T1,T2>` combines 2 hashes:

```
// From System.Web.Util.HashCodeCombiner
internal static int CombineHashCodes(int h1, int h2)
{
    return (((h1 << 5) + h1) ^ h2);
}
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/tuple.cs,1806cf6634f5a371

It's really tricky to replace the GetHashCode() implementation for the component types, but you might introduce an additional term after you combine the hashes.

Eg, XOR in the concatenation of the components' sign bits to ensure that Hash(d,-d) != Hash(-d,d).

```
    internal static int GetSign(double d)
    {
        return d >= 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        var signs = GetSign(d2) << 1 | GetSign(d1);
        var h = CombineHashCodes(d1.GetHashCode(), d2.GetHashCode());
        return h ^ signs;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make the problem better. If we define our own double hasher as  `public static int MyHash(double d) {
  if (d == 0) return 0;
  long w = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(d);
  return CombineHashCodes((int)w, (int)(w>>32));
 }


 public static int MyHash(double x, double y) {
  return CombineHashCodes(MyHash(x), MyHash(y));
    }` then we still have the property that `MyHash(x, -y) == MyHash(-x, y)`!

Comment: The OP's code *isn't* XORing the hashes together.  They're multiplying each hash by 23 and then adding them without considering overflow.  That's different, in fairly similar ways to why your code is different from a straight XOR (it offsets one of them before adding the bits), which explains why this has the same problem, as Eric mentions.

Comment: If I modify the left shift to a right shift, this answer solves my problem. I have marked this as the accepted answer. Thanks David!

Comment: For clarity: this solution is not a new hash method for double, but it solves my problem with using the built-in double.GetHashCode().

Answer (score 1):

You could hash over `long`. Replace `int hash` with `long hash`, like:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked
    {
        long hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + field1.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + field2.GetHashCode();

        return hash.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Now you removed the overflow problem. And from a test I've done (on a single couple of `double` :-) ) your problem.